# Doing a readLine inside an if

Tags: haskell, io

I'm writing a small command-line utility in Haskell which should accept a command with an optional command-line argument - but if the argument is not present, the user should be prompted to enter it*. For example:

```
$ my_prog add item_name
Adding... done

$ my_prog add
Enter item name: item_name
Adding... done
```

My initial attempt looked something like this:

```hs
add args = do
    let id = if length args > 0
        then head args
        else input where
            input <- readLine
    -- Do stuff with id
    putStrLn id
```

Which fails to parse at the `<-`.

*I have since decided that this is a silly idea, but I thought I'd ask the question anyway.

Comment: Aside: it is usually better to use `not (null args)` than `length args > 0`. In fact, since you're using `head` later on, it's probably best to just pattern-match, with `case args of [] -> readLine; x : _ -> return x`

Comment: @BenMillwood The pattern match makes sense, but what's the deal with `not (null args)`? Does Haskell need `O(n)` time to get the length?

Comment: Precisely. Consider in particular the case of an infinite list! (here it's pretty safe to assume that `args` is not infinite, but it's often the case that if your algorithm fails in the infinite case then it performs badly in the large case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are attempting to use the `do`-notation inside the `if`, this will not work (and besides, won't typecheck since the whole `if` is outside the `IO` monad).

```
add args = do
    id <- if length args > 0
              then return $ head args
              else readLine
    putStrLn id
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense now - for some reason I didn't make the leap to putting the `<-` outside the `if`!